# SSL Certificate Error for Docker - Flask Application

Tags: python, docker, flask, plotly-dash

Deployed a flask application and binded it to the ssl certificate to run on "https:" with the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     path = "/usr/local/nginx/ssl/"
     context = (path  + 'abc.crt' , path + 'abc.key')
     app.run_server(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',ssl_context=context)
```

Now when I run this script directly through python (python scriptname.py), it works fine,
However when I run in inside the docker container ,I get the following error:

```
  Exception in thread Thread-2: 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1005, in inner
     fd=fd,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 848, in make_server
     host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 766, in __init__
     self.socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 661, in wrap_socket
     **kwargs
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1158, in wrap_socket
     ciphers=ciphers)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 750, in __init__
     self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)

   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I guess the container is searching for the file elsewhere, this is my docker run command:

```
docker run -it --network="host" -p 8050:8050 -v /home/a/b/c:/app abc:1.1
```

What am i missing here?

**Edit** : Dockerfile

```
 FROM python:3.6
 COPY . /app
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
 CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: plz post here Dockerfile

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev Done in edit.

Comment: Why do you have the `path=" "` this won't work inside the docker file. Because your app is in `/app`

Comment: @TarunLalwani the path is not blank as mentioned above ,i haven't specified it above.

Comment: Is it getting copies inside the container with `COPY . /app`, if not then you need to get those files also inside the container, and the right way to do it is to use volume mapping to provide such files

Comment: @TarunLalwani You mean I need to copy the certificate inside the container?, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Docker container will only be able to access what you copied inside it or what your mapped to it while running. So you have 2 options. One add a COPY statement to copy the certs, but looking at the current docker file, your certs were outside the `app` folder and hence not copied. So you should use `-v` option to map the certs while running the container.  `docker run -it --network="host" -p 8050:8050 -v /home/certs/path:/home/certs/path -v /home/a/b/c:/app abc:1.1`

Comment: @TarunLalwani That was simple , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker container will only be able to access what you copied inside it or what your mapped to it while running.

So you have 2 options. First option is to add a COPY statement to copy the certs, but looking at the current docker file, your certs were outside the `app` folder and hence not copied.

Other option is to use `-v` option to map the certs while running the container.

```sh
docker run -it --network="host" -p 8050:8050 -v /home/certs/path:/home/certs/path -v /home/a/b/c:/app abc:1.1
```

But in a production like environment I would suggest you don't do this. You should use a `nginx` and `uwsgi` and make sure the your terminate the SSL at `nginx`

See the below repo for such an option

https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker